# Cloud build - Terraform Execution - manual apply approve

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-build, infrastructure-as-code

It's possible to create a manual iteration inside a cloud build execution to permit a manual approve of terraform apply flow?

Comment: No. Cloud Build is straightforward. You can't stop the pipeline in the middle

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `@guillaume blaquiere`, Currently. you cannot **pause** or **stop** an ongoing `Cloud Build execution` just for user input.

In addition, There is an existing [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/186026188), you can star this feature request and add `Me too` in the thread. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it but there's no guarantee when it will be implemented.